# Adding a frame breaks .clipShape() SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

So I'm loading the image in a custom struct called 'RemoteImage' that takes in a URL and loads it into a SwiftUI Image(). For some reason, when I have .clipShape() on the RemoteImage(), it clips the shape to a circle (although it's the wrong width/height, but when I set the .frame() to the desired width/height, the image is displayed with the correct width/height but is no longer a circle. Not sure how to fix:

```
RemoteImage(url: image)
    .clipShape(Circle())
    .frame(width: 82, height: 82)

struct RemoteImage: View {
    private enum LoadState {
        case loading, success, failure
    }
    
    private class Loader: ObservableObject {
        var data = Data()
        var state = LoadState.loading
        
        init(url: String) {
            guard let parsedURL = URL(string: url) else {
                fatalError("Invalid URL: \(url)")
            }
            
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: parsedURL) { data, response, error in
                if let data = data, data.count > 0 {
                    self.data = data
                    self.state = .success
                } else {
                    self.state = .failure
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.objectWillChange.send()
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
    
    @StateObject private var loader: Loader
    var loading: Image
    var failure: Image
    
    var body: some View {
        selectImage()
            .resizable()
    }
    
    init(url: String, loading: Image = Image(""), failure: Image = Image(systemName: "multiply.circle")) {
        _loader = StateObject(wrappedValue: Loader(url: url))
        self.loading = loading
        self.failure = failure
    }
    
    private func selectImage() -> Image {
        switch loader.state {
        case .loading:
            return loading
        case .failure:
            return failure
        default:
            if let image = UIImage(data: loader.data) {
                return Image(uiImage: image)
            } else {
                return failure
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does swapping the modifiers work?

Comment: No, it does not. @George

Comment: This needs a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine, Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4, however clipShape is better to apply *after* frame.

Let me suppose that you just wanted aspect ratio

```
var body: some View {
    selectImage()
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)    // << here !!
}
```

Comment: Also tested on Xcode Version 14.0.1 (14A400) for a more complicated cases, and it works.